# uidatepicker first letter of the selected day is cropped

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have place a UIDatePicker inside a view of fixed width, and the first letter is always cropped. I have tried modifying the width of the picker but it only makes bigger the separation between the different selectors, the date always gets the first letter of the day of the week cropped. Is there any way to change this?

The picker is placed with constraints between the margins of the view.

Two examples of how changing the width does not help

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How narrow are you trying to make your Date Picker?

From Apple's docs:

> **Appearance**
>
> The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable. You
>   should integrate date pickers in your layout using Auto Layout.
>
> Although date pickers can be resized, they should be used at their
>   intrinsic content size.

and

> **Internationalization**
>
> Date pickers handle their own internationalization; the only thing you
>   need to do is specify the appropriate locale. ...
>
> ... The width of the date picker automatically accommodates for the
>   length of the localization.

So, while you *may* find a way around this... it may also cause more problems down the road.

Answer (score -1):

I created quick project to test your scenario and it works fine as you see in the below image. Here the UIVIew(Green box) and the picker inside the UIView have fixed width.

I suggest you to reduce the width of your picker to keep it smaller than the parent UIView. And set Horizontally in container constrain for the picker, so that it will float inside the UIView perfectly in the center.

[image]